# Is there an equivalent to the Rails command/feature "rake routes" for Grails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grails, model-view-controller, routes, grails-2.0

Is there an equivalent to the Rails command/feature "rake routes" for Grails?

I have many routes in my current application and would like to get a better understanding of them to solve a few issues.

Comment: Could you please describe what does it mean 'rake routes', for non-RoR guys?

Comment: rake routes will list all of your defined routes, which is useful for tracking down routing problems in your app, or giving you a good overview of the URLs in an app you’re trying to get familiar with. from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html

Comment: example of output - http://wescreative.com/2011/08/how-to-find-rails-app-routes-rake/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Grails version 2.3 has a new feature called [URL Mapping reports](http://grails.io/post/50643596608/road-to-grails-2-3-restful-url-mappings-and-url).  This is the equivalent of the `rake routes` command in the Rails framework.

```
grails url-mappings-report
```

It displays a list of the URL Mappings in the application and the controller / action they map to.

Comment: it doesn't traverse the controllers and actions for a comprehensive list? :(